# Windows 10 update rolling back for cumulative updates

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I have been facing issues with windows update on the 2 year old laptop from beginning. I have installed various major versions but windows automatic updates fail to install cumulative updates. Cumulative updates are installed almost 100% and then shows "undoing changes" message.

I have tried all the workarounds I found on net including checking the disk, resetting update components, manual update and what not. Nothing has worked.

Also while going through major updates, sometimes activation goes away and I have to reset the windows to get activation back.

Recently I found few lines in CBS log which I think might be helpful in finding the reason.

```
2021-10-02 14:24:12, Info                  CSI    000014b3 The queue has completed running, and AI failures have occured.
2021-10-02 14:24:12, Info                  CSI    000014b4 ==Error Summary Start==
2021-10-02 14:24:12, Error                 CSI    000014b5 (F) Installer: SppInstaller  Binary Name: cmiadapter.dll ErrorCode: c004f01f Phase: 34   Mode: Install (upgrade) Component: Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP-Component-SKU-Core-License, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, ProcessorArchitecture=amd64, versionScope=NonSxS[gle=0x80004005]
2021-10-02 14:24:12, Error                 CSI    000014b6 (F) Installer: SppInstaller  Binary Name: cmiadapter.dll ErrorCode: c004f01f Phase: 34   Mode: Install (upgrade) Component: Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP-Component-SKU-CoreSingleLanguage-License, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, ProcessorArchitecture=amd64, versionScope=NonSxS[gle=0x80004005]
2021-10-02 14:24:12, Info                  CSI    000014b7 ==Error Summary End==
2021-10-02 14:24:12, Error                 CBS    Startup: Failed to process advanced operation queue, startupPhase: 0.  A rollback transaction will be created. [HRESULT = 0x800f0922 - CBS_E_INSTALLERS_FAILED]
```

I tried a clean boot but update didn't go through. I searched online but not able to find much help regarding the errors shown in log.

Any hint how can I fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: In order to answer this question I would need to know which update you are attempting to install and which cumulative update was successfully installed last.  I also would need to know what version of Windows 10 you have installed

Comment: I am attempting to install kb5005565 for x64 (latest cumulative update).

There was no cumulative update installed after upgrade to 21H1. 

Windows version is Windows 10 Home Single Language 21H1 
OS Build 19043.985

Comment: You will have to provide us the log for Windows Update. 19043.985 is several months old (May 2021)

Answer (score 0):

Normally the best way to solve a year or 2 old update issue is to do a Windows 10 Repair Install.

Go to the Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. There are 3 ways to proceed, according to the severity of the error.

(1) Keep Everything: Best if it works and your computer comes back just the way you had set it up except repaired.  Always have a backup, but generally nothing will be lost.

(2) Keep Data: Necessary if the operating system damage is extensive. Keeps the User Profile and makes software install quite easy. Always have a backup, but data is not usually lost.

(3) Keep Nothing: Deletes the User Profile and all else and is essentially a fresh install.  Be certain you have backed up all your data. "Keep Nothing" is necessary if the User Profile is damaged, because broken User Profiles cannot be repaired and it is generally easier to back up and start over if the User Profile is damaged. It depends on the precise situation.

Keep Everything is always the best way to start and may fix the issue for you.